# Clone a AAD to another tenant with B2C feature on

Tags: azure-active-directory

Clone a AAD to another tenant with B2C feature on, those b2c AAD store our information with to sign in with Dynamics CRM portal.

Answer (score 1):

there is no easy clone button to do this in terms of creating another azure ad tenant and copying all the objects over. you will have to re-create all your user objects and objects/permissions in the new tenant, with powershell scripts or some other means. of course you can't move over app registrations and such. those will all need to be recreated as well. 
This may help a bit with the B2C User portion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration you need to export basically a userlist and import it into your new B2C Tenant.